# Target.Adress = Range

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, range, target

how can I make a Target.Adress from  1 cell to a range of cells?

```
If Target.Address = "$G$7" And WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Target) Then Target = -Abs(Target)
End Sub
```

Changing G7 to G7:G49

I tried different examples like

```
If Target.Address = "(G7:G49)" And WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Target) Then Target = -Abs(Target)
End Sub
```

and others... but it didn´t work.

Comment: `Not Intersect(Range("G7:G49"),Target) is Nothing`

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of using `.Address`, use `Intersect`.
- Loop over the cells in the `Intersect`ion.
- Assuming this is within a `Worksheet_Change` handler, disable events to prevent an infinite loop, and enable at the end.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G7:G49"))

If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo SafeExit
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(cell.Value) Then
        cell.Value = -Abs(cell.Value)
    End If
Next

SafeExit:
Application.EnableEvents = True
```